# Where I can see phpMyAdmin release/schedule dates?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've tried, but failed to find the source, where I can see the schedule of phpMyAdmin release dates.

For example, on official site, it's 4.8.4 version, however, 5.0 version is on github. 
Where I can see when it goes it production?

Answer (score 1):

According to the README on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin):

> You can get the newest release at https://www.phpmyadmin.net/.

In the same README file on GitHub, it states:

> - `STABLE` is the current stable release.
> - `master` is the development branch.

When you view the stable branch on GitHub (from [this link](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/tree/STABLE)), you'll find it's the same version as the one on https://www.phpmyadmin.net/.

To answer your question, you'll have to monitor the website to know when the next version is released. Just eyeballing the Milestones tab on GitHub, it would seem they're working on two minor patches at the time of this writing.

Keep your eye on the main website, like it says so.